# React Native cannot find module

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, node-modules, background-task

I am trying to build a basic notification app that uses the react-native-background-task module. For some reasons it gives this error: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'schedule')**

Below is the code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task';
// import { Notifications, Permissions, Constants } from 'expo';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'


console.log("object")
BackgroundTask.define(async () => {
    console.log("bgtask")
 // if time is 12pm, fire off a request with axios to fetch the pills info
  
  // Notification configuration object
  const localNotification = {
        title: text,
        body: 'msg',
        data: data,
        ios: {
          sound: true
        }
      }

 // trigger notification, note that on ios if the app is open(in foreground) the notification will not show so you will need to find some ways to handling it which is discribed here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications

      Notifications
         .presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification)
         .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
         })


      BackgroundTask.finish()
})

export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("uef")
        const componentDidMount = async () => {
            // allows the app to recieve notifications (permission stuff)
            console.log("cdm")
            registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(() => {
                console.log("bg sche")
                BackgroundTask.schedule()
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log("err")
                console.log(e)
            });

        }
        componentDidMount()
    }, []);

    

  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
        console.log("reg")
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
            console.log("permission not granted")
      return;
    }
        console.log("permission granted")
    let deviceToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()

  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js \o start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The problem comes when I do the BackgroundTask.schedule() function. It says in the error that BackgroundTask is undefined. I know for a fact that all the other functions worked fine because the console.logs all get printed right until "bg sche" and then it goes and print "err" in the catch block.

I also tried to use ctrl + click on the package name that should bring me to source where this BackgroundTask object is exported but it doesn't work like it usually does for other modules. So I think for some reasons the module can't be found but I have already installed it and it is in my package.json file and I see it in my node_modules folder.